# How to set start and end boundary in perl

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures

This is my code

```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my $string=" The UNIX grep filters the lines of a file based on a regular expression.Perl's grep can filter any list of value based on any condition. This Perl code implements a basic version of the UNIX grep:  ";
   $string =~ m/grep/;
   print "$& $'\n";
```

This is my output:

> grep can filter any list of value based on any condition.
>   This Perl code implements a basic version of the UNIX grep:

But I want Output is

> grep can filter any list of value based on any condition.
>   This Perl code

Can Anyone help  me ??

Comment: `print((split /(?=grep)/, $string)[1], "\n")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I change like                                          print((split /(?=filters)/, $string)[1], "\n");     The Output is [filters the lines of a file based on a regular expression.Perl's grep can filter any list of value based on any condition.This Perl code implements a basic version of the UNIX grep:]    It cannot set end boundary  value .I want print until [code] what i do

Comment: Ah okay. You want `print $string =~ /(filters.*?code)/, "\n"`

Comment: Thanks sir I am using like this [ print((split /(?=filters)|(?=code)/, $string)[1], "\n");] . Output is [filters the lines of a file based on a regular expression.Perl's grep can filter any list of value based on any condition.
This Perl ]  code is not printed in this output What I do

Comment: You use the solution I gave you instead

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
$string =~ m/\..*?(grep.*?code)/;
print "$1\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . When I am using this  code following error has occur .[Use of uninitialized value $1 in concatenation (.) or string at str.pl line 13.]

Comment: Can you share the complete block of code so it would be easier to figure out the error as the solution that I've provide works perfectly fine for me.